# whois command is not recognized

Tags: windows, networking, network-protocols, whois, nmap

I have downloaded nmap. As far as I know, it supports the 'whois' tool. When I try to type the following: whois yahoo.com (as example). I got the following error: 
'whois' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. Can anyone tell me what I'm missing? Do I need to install something other than nmap itself?

Comment: `whois` and `nmap` are 2 different tools, as far as I know.

Comment: The `whois` command is not part of `nmap`. On my Debian 6 system it comes from its own `whois` package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, this tool isn't part of `nmap`

```
blender ~ $ pacman -Qo `which whois`
/usr/bin/whois is owned by whois 5.0.16-1
```

And in fact, `nmap` doesn't supply much more than `nmap` and some its own binaries:

```
blender ~ $ pacman -Ql nmap | grep "bin"
nmap /usr/bin/
nmap /usr/bin/ncat
nmap /usr/bin/ndiff
nmap /usr/bin/nmap
nmap /usr/bin/nmapfe
nmap /usr/bin/nping
nmap /usr/bin/xnmap
nmap /usr/bin/zenmap
```

Check if there is a `whois` package for your distro.

Answer (score 2):

Nmap can perform queries with the whois protocol using the [whois script](http://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/whois-ip.html) like so:

```
nmap --script whois -sn yahoo.com
```

Note that the whois script was renamed to whois-ip in Nmap 6.45 (revision 31527) and [whois-domain](http://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/whois-domain.html) was added. So you can do:

```
nmap --script whois-ip,whois-domain -sn yahoo.com
```

or simply:

```
nmap --script whois* -sn yahoo.com
```

In addition to the `--script` argument, the `-sn` argument tells Nmap not to perform a port scan (since that's probably not what you want).

Based on your error description, it sounds like you are on Windows. Microsoft has a `whois` utility available as part of the SysInternals suite. You can get it [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897435.aspx).